# Slick 3 - ForeignKeys are not generated

Tags: mysql, scala, persistence, slick, play-slick

I cannot seem to find a solution to this weird bug:

```
class Names(tag: Tag) extends Table[Name](tag, "NAME") with Identifiable[Name]{
  def firstName = column[String]("firstName")
  def lastName = column[String]("lastName")
  def profileId = column[Int]("profileId")
  def * = (id.?, firstName, lastName, profileId) <> ((Name.apply _).tupled, Name.unapply)
  def profileFk = foreignKey("profile_fk", profileId, TableQuery[Profiles])(_.id, onDelete=ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)
}

class PhoneNumbers(tag: Tag) extends Table[PhoneNumber](tag, "PHONENUMBER") with Identifiable[PhoneNumber] {
  def number = column[String]("number")
  def kind = column[String]("kind")
  def profileId = column[Int]("profileId")
  def * = (id.?, number, kind, profileId) <> ((PhoneNumber.apply _).tupled, PhoneNumber.unapply)
  def profileFk = foreignKey("profile_fk", profileId, TableQuery[Profiles])(_.id, onDelete=ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)
}
```

and the profile class consists of an id field only. Identifiable provides the id-property.

I am using Slick 3 with MySQL.

For Names a foreignKey to Profiles is generated, for PhoneNumbers not. Why? There seems to be no difference?

**Update:**

Here the relevant statements:

```
create table `PHONENUMBER` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`number` TEXT NOT NULL,`kind` TEXT NOT NULL,`profileId` INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

And:

```
alter table `PHONENUMBER` add constraint `profile_fk` foreign key(`profileId`) references `PROFILE`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete CASCADE
```

Complete Output:

create table `PROFILE` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`userId` INTEGER NOT NULL)

create table `VERSION` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL,`vector` INTEGER NOT NULL)

create table `NAME` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`firstName` TEXT NOT NULL,`lastName` TEXT NOT NULL,`profileId` INTEGER NOT NULL,`versionId` INTEGER NOT NULL)

create table `PHONENUMBER` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`number` TEXT NOT NULL,`kind` TEXT NOT NULL,`profileId` INTEGER NOT NULL,`versionId` INTEGER NOT NULL)

create table `VIEW` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
create table `PHONENUMBERS_VIEWS` (`phoneNumber` INTEGER NOT NULL,`view` INTEGER NOT NULL)

create table `CREDENTIALS` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`username` TEXT NOT NULL,`password` TEXT NOT NULL,`userId` INTEGER NOT NULL)

create table `USER` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)

create table `API_KEY` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`token` TEXT NOT NULL,`deviceId` TEXT NOT NULL,`credentialsId` INTEGER NOT NULL)

alter table `PROFILE` add constraint `user_fk` foreign key(`userId`) references `USER`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete NO ACTION

alter table `NAME` add constraint `profile_fk` foreign key(`profileId`) references `PROFILE`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete CASCADE

alter table `NAME` add constraint `version_fk` foreign key(`versionId`) references `VERSION`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete NO ACTION

alter table `PHONENUMBER` add constraint `profile_fk` foreign key(`profileId`) references `PROFILE`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete CASCADE

alter table `PHONENUMBER` add constraint `version_fk` foreign key(`versionId`) references `VERSION`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete NO ACTION

alter table `PHONENUMBERS_VIEWS` add constraint `phoneNumber_fk` foreign key(`phoneNumber`) references `PHONENUMBER`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete NO ACTION
alter table `PHONENUMBERS_VIEWS` add constraint `view_fk` foreign key(`view`) references `VIEW`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete NO ACTION

alter table `CREDENTIALS` add constraint `user_fk` foreign key(`userId`) references `USER`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete NO ACTION

alter table `API_KEY` add constraint `credentials_fk` foreign key(`credentialsId`) references `CREDENTIALS`(`id`) on update NO ACTION on delete NO ACTION

` symbol is hidden because of markdown, but there in the original output

**EDIT 2**:

```
val profiles = TableQuery[Profiles]
val names = TableQuery[Names]
val phoneNumbers = TableQuery[PhoneNumbers]
val views = TableQuery[Views]
val phoneNumbersToViews = TableQuery[PhoneNumbersToViews]
val users = TableQuery[Users]
val credentials = TableQuery[CredentialsSchema]
val apiKeys = TableQuery[ApiKeys]
val versions = TableQuery[Versions]

val schema = profiles.schema ++
  versions.schema ++
  names.schema ++
  phoneNumbers.schema ++
  views.schema ++
  phoneNumbersToViews.schema ++
  credentials.schema ++
  users.schema ++
  apiKeys.schema

SlickDB().run(DBIO.seq(
  schema.create
))

schema.createStatements.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Did you created the added the profileFk after your table was generated ? I will try to drop the table and will recreate again.

Comment: Already tried. Did not change anything :/

Comment: Can post your table create statements and drop statements ?  Also lets us know if you solved this problem.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can debug/see the generated sql or post a link? I can not seem to find it.

Comment: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/schemas.html#data-definition-language. See the bottom, use createstatements and dropstatements and to print the generated sql.

Comment: Updated my post. Do drop statements matter? The create statements seem to be correct... mmhhm

Comment: The only other reason, I will verify is if you are crating any table with myISAM engine. myISAM does not support foreign key as such will not throw any error if issue a creation of foreign key, if the syntax is right. If thats not the case please post your scala code where you create and drop tables.

Comment: I am not sure, which code you meant, but I edited my post.

Comment: FYI, Your create statements contains two foreign key constraints with same name "profile_fk",but in code they are named as "profile_fk" and "profileA_fk"

Comment: You are right. I forgot to change it here, my current code is using the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "For Names a foreignKey to Profiles is generated, for PhoneNumbers not.
>   Why? There seems to be no difference?"

I think the lack of a difference is the problem here.

You've used the same foreign key name ("profile_fk") for `Names.profileFk` and `PhoneNumbers.profileFk`. The MySQL foreign key names need to be unique.

I'd suggest replacing "profile_fk" with "name_profile_fk" and "phonenumber_profile_fk".

However, you should be seeing an exception. The first of the alter table statements you included...

```
alter table NAME add constraint profile_fk foreign key(profileId) references PROFILE(id) on update NO ACTION on delete CASCADE
```

... should run OK, but the second...

```
alter table PHONENUMBER add constraint profile_fk foreign key(profileId) references PROFILE(id) on update NO ACTION on delete CASCADE
```

...is where there should be an exception.

If you're not seeing an exception, it could be that your application is terminating before the future you execute returns.  You can test that out by placing an await around your `SlickDB().run` command. E.g.,

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
Await.result(
  SlickDB().run(DBIO.seq(schema.create))
  , 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Seems like you are totally right. Now I get a "Unexpected exception[MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Can't write; duplicate key in table " exception. Thanks a lot!